# Select language based on country select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Based on the country select populate the languages in that country
ex: If country drop-down is India and the language drop-down will contain [Hindi,Telugu,Tamil,Marathi,Malayalam,...]
Is this possible in jquery or rails gem??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: yes its possible in query

Comment: @UnniBabu is there any available plugin to go with it?? if so please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is even a gem called [country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) for that purpose that prepares you both the jquery (javascript) and ruby code needed

Comment: country_select is used to load the country list right? i have a country list using carmen.Now, i need to load the language for the selected country.

Comment: country select is used for both. However if you have the country list from a different place, a simple select box is enough for country selection